# How to get class public string in JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee

I'm trying to get some config static values from my config class in jsp.
I tried this but it is not working.
Please guide me here.

JSP code

```
<%@ page import="com.helper.AppConfig" %>

<c:out value="${Appconfig.themeGitDir}"/>
```

And this is my config class

```
public class AppConfig {
    public static String database = "themegit";
    public static String databaseUser = "root";
    public static String databasePassword = "";
    public static String userTable = "users";
    public static String themeGitDir = "C:/Users/HP/Desktop/theme-git/";
    }
```

Comment: So it was showing when i use apache 8.5. But now it is not showing. Maybe because right now i'm using 7.4? @ Karol Dowbecki

Comment: Is your JSP code a direct copy/paste? Why does your JSP's `value` attribute use `Appconfig` when the class is `AppConfig`?